# How do I get a virtual timestamp in a coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines

I want to get a timestamp in a function in a testable way. Using functions like [getTimeMillis](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/get-time-millis.html) doesn't work in a test as runTest will skip delays. `TestScope.currentTime` on the other hand only works in tests. I need one way that works in both cases.

```kotlin
suspend fun getCurrentTime(): Long {
  return // what to do here? 
}

@Test
fun testMyCode() = runTest {
  delay(20)

  assertThat(this.currentTime).isEqualTo(20)
  assertThat(getCurrentTime()).isEqualTo(20)
}
```

I found [DelayController](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/) but it's deprecated. Is there another way to get a timestamp from the current CoroutineContext?

Comment: It seems that there is currently not a standard solution. You can inject the "clock" dependency as discussed here: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/8626198/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-current-clock-time-in-productio

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an approach that will work:

```kotlin
val CoroutineContext.nanoTime : Long
  get() = (this[ContinuationInterceptor] as? TestDispatcher)
    ?.scheduler?.currentTime?.times(1_000_000)
    ?: System.nanoTime()
```

And you use it like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getCurrentTime(): Long {
  return coroutineContext.nanoTime / 1_000_000
}
```

I'm still surprised this is not a language feature tbh.